# Menu is not closing when Page size down

Tags: javascript, visualforce

Here resize main page like mobile screen kind of size.then now click

1. Login to community portal
2. On dashboard/any page, click on hamburger menu.
3. The menu list should be displayed.
4. Again click on hamburger menu icon. or click any free space on page.

Expected result:
The menu list should be closed.

Actual Result:
The menu list is not closed .

...
Using JS and CSS.
..........

```
<div class="nav-pane">
<nav id="primary-accord" class="primary-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="CommunityDashboard" id="nav-dash" class="no-sub dashboard">{!DashboardLbl}</a></li>
        <li style="{!IF(isPartnerUser,"display:inline","display:none")}"><a href="CommunityPartnerLanding" id="nav-partners" class="no-sub partners">{!forPartnersMenuLabel}</a></li>
        <li><a href="CommunityAppsAndLicenses" id="nav-al" class="no-sub apps">{!appsAndLicensesMenuLabel}</a></li>
        <li style="{!IF(isAdmin,"display:inline","display:none")}"><a href="CommunityManageUsers" id="A2" class="no-sub users">{!manageUsersMenuLabel}</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://cradlepointecm.com/" id="A3" class="no-sub ecm" target="_blank">{!myEcmMenuLabel}</a></li>
        <li><a href="CommunityUserProfile" id="A4" class="no-sub profile">{!myProfileMenuLabel}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="nav-support" class="sub support">{!mySupportMenuLabel}</a>
            <ul id="menu-support">
                <li><a href="CommunitySupportLanding">{!supportHomeLabel}</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://professionalservices.cradlepoint.com/" target="_blank">{!profServicesMenuLabel}</a></li>
                <li><a href="CommunityKnowledgebase">{!knowledgebaseMenuLabel}</a></li>
                <li><a href="CommunityCasePage">{!supportCasesMenuLabel}</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://cradlepoint.com/support/enterprise" target="_blank">{!productInfoMenuLabel}</a></li>                        
                <!-- li id="liveagent_menu_online_5735000000000Ts" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript://Chat" onclick="liveagent.startChat('5735000000000Ts')">{!liveChatMenuLabel}</a></li>
                <li id="liveagent_menu_offline_5735000000000Ts" style="display: none;"><a href="CommunityCasePage">{!liveChatMenuLabel}</a></li-->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

.................................

```
<c:CommunityNavBar />

<section id="whole-body">
    <!--The header row -->
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item one-whole">
            <div class="header-container">
                <!-- <div class="header_bg_gray"></div>-->
                <div class="header-wide">
                    <div class="site-width header">
                        <div class="breadcrumb palm--hide lap--hide">
                            <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Wirestone,'Images/Header_Navigation_Images/CP3_Home.png')}" /><a href="#">{!DashboardLabel}</a></div>
                        <div class="title-full"><div class="title-left">Your</div><div class="title-img palm--hide lap--hide"><img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Wirestone,'Images/Header_Navigation_Images/CP3_Logo.png')}" alt="CP3"/></div><div class="title-right">{!DashboardLabel}</div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="header_bg_black"></div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End header row -->
```